# How to replace duplicate words in a column with just one word in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a few million strings that relate to file paths in my database;
due to a third party program these paths have become nested like below:

```
C:\files\thirdparty\thirdparty\thirdparty\thirdparty\thirdparty\thirdparty\unique_bit_here\
```

I want update the entries so that `thirdparty\thirdparty\etc` becomes `\thirdparty`.

I have tried this code:

```
UPDATE table
SET Field = REPLACE(Field, 'tables\thirdparty\%thirdparty\%\', 'tables\thirdparty\')
```

Comment: can you post your tried code ??

Comment: Can you show us some code, so we can see what you have tried?

Comment: Do you want to replace only 2 `thirdparty` in succession, or any number of them?

Comment: what is your goal? do you want to update existing string or just manipulating on SELECT query?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen any number

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table WHERE Field LIKE '%\thirdparty\thirdparty\%')
BEGIN
    UPDATE table SET Field = REPLACE(Field, '\thirdparty\thirdparty\', '\thirdparty\')
END
```

Comment: @eftpotrm - can't we do without while loop?

Comment: @rajeshpanchal Loops can usually be replaced by set-based operations, but at the expense of a more complex query. If the loop's going to a have very large number of iterations it's worth rewriting as set-based to improve performance; in this case there just aren't enough possible iterations for the performance to get nasty, so I'd go for the simpler code that's easier to write and maintain.

Comment: just thought I'd pop back and say thanks again @eftpotrm your code is saving my bacon again.

Comment: @eftpotrm what would you know, this has happened again, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

So do you want something like this?

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('tables\thirdparty\%thirdparty\%\',0,CHARINDEX('\','tables\thirdparty\%thirdparty\%\',0)) + '\thirdparty\'
```

OR

```
UPDATE table
SET Field = REPLACE(Field, Field, (SELECT SUBSTRING(Field,0,CHARINDEX('\',Field,0)) + '\thirdparty\'))
```

Comment: Does replace really support wildcards?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - yes it supports wildcards.

Comment: @Dansmith - may I know what was the error while updating?

Comment: hmmm btw it should work. As I have already tried at my local. with your provided string.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid using a loop with the following technique:

```
Update TABLE
SET Field = left(Field,charindex('*',replace(Field, 'thirdparty\', '*'))-1)+'thirdparty\'+right(Field,charindex('*',reverse(replace(Field, 'thirdparty\', '*')))-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Its too late, but I just guess if I want replace a single word in repeating multiple time same word as he want. This will replace all with append a single time '\thirdparty'...

Check this.

```
Declare @table table(Field varchar(max))
insert into @table values('C:\files\thirdparty\thirdparty\thirdparty\thirdparty\thirdparty\thirdparty\unique_bit_here\')
,('C:\files\thirdparty\thirdparty\thirdparty\thirdparty\thirdparty\thirdparty\unique_bit_here\1')
,('C:\files\thirdparty\thirdparty\thirdparty\thirdparty\thirdparty\thirdparty\unique_bit_here\2')
,('C:\files\thirdparty\thirdparty\thirdparty\thirdparty\thirdparty\thirdparty\unique_bit_here\3')
,('C:\files\thirdparty\thirdparty\thirdparty\thirdparty\thirdparty\thirdparty\unique_bit_here\4')

UPDATE @table
SET Field = SUBSTRING (Field, 1, CHARINDEX('\thirdparty', Field ) ) +  'thirdparty\'
--replace (Field , 'thirdparty\' ,'')  
+ reverse( SUBSTRING ( REVERSE(Field), 1, CHARINDEX(reverse('\thirdparty'), REVERSE(Field) )-2 ) )
--REPLACE(Field, 'tables\thirdparty\%thirdparty\%\', 'tables\thirdparty\')

select * from @table
```

Comment: yes it can be the solution, I also given the same solution. bit changed but almost same.

Comment: Yes, your update is ok, but in select you use wildcard which is wrong. I try that too see above.